# Probability for Three of a Kind in Poker via Counting

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

For a standard deck of 52 cards, what is the probability of getting three of a kind in poker (i.e three of the cards are the same number or rank and the remaining two cards are different / not a pair - e.g. Ace of hearts, Ace of spade, Ace of diamond, Two of diamond, three of spade).

I understand how to calculate the problem using nCk method, so I know the answer is $\frac{88}{4165}$ .

I am trying to calculate via counting and my thinking is follows.

First taking the case of AAABC,

The first card can be any chosen out of any of the 52 cards (so 1 card out of 4 suit cards is chosen, with the 1 card being any card out of the 52)
the second card is chosen out of the 3 cards remaining
the third card is chosen out of the 2 cards remaining
the fourth card cannot be the remaining 1 card, so is taken out of 48 possible cards
the fifth card cannot be the remaining 1 card (of 1st suit) and remaining 3 cards (of 2nd suit), so it is taken out of 44 possible cards

$\frac{52 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 48 \cdot 44}{52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48} = \frac{44}{20825}$

At this point, my answer is off by a factor of 10 and I understand that I am not accounting for the fact that the cards do not have to be in the order of AAABC (e.g. can be BCAAA etc.)

I am not understanding how to get to the 10 and/or why the 10 is the permutation count that is to be adjusted for (I do understand that the adjustment has to be multiplied).

I have read some threads explain it as $\frac{5!}{3!2!}$ or that it is the number of ways to obtain three of a kind in 5 card draw, but I am not understanding why that is the case.

The furthest I got up to for accounting for permutation count was using the formula for permutation with repetition (i.e how many ways AAABC can be ordered, with 3 repeated A), which ends up being 20, rather than 10.

Specifically, I thought the permutation count would be $\frac{5!}{3!}$ , which is equal to 20, so I am not off by a factor of 2.

I guess I am not understand the specific reasoning why there is an additional 2! discount

Thank you in advance

Comment: same of what kind, same colour, shape or number?

Comment: by three of a kind I mean same number (so ace of heart, ace of spade, ace of diamond)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a specific hand, say $AS, AH, AD, 2C, 3D$, there are $5!=120$ orders that you can draw it in.  You have counted this hand $12$ times.  As you counted there are $3!=6$ different orders you can draw the aces in and $2!=2$ different orders you can draw the other two cards.  The ratio $\frac {120}{12}=10$ is what you are looking for.

I think this approach is prone to error.  Your denominator is all the ordered five card draws from a deck.  If you want to use that you should count all the ordered ways to draw three of a kind.  Alternately you could count the unordered number of five card combinations for the denominator, then count the number of unordered hands that are three of a kind.  Either approach will get the correct answer.

Comment: I guess the reason why I am trying to do it this method is I am trying to expand my understanding from the simpler cases of using this counting method. It should work, but my understanding is not good enough for follow through completely. I understand it's not the best way to do it. I know how to get the unordered five card and unordered denominator. Would you please expand a bit on what you mean by counting all the ordered ways to draw the three kind? thank you in advance

Comment: Counting the ordered ways to draw three of a kind is counting all the draws of five cards that do that, considering different orders distinct.  Your denominator of $52 \cdot 51 \cdot 50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48$ is the number of ordered ways to draw any five cards.  It considers a draw of $A2345$ of spades different from a draw of $5432A$ of spades.  This is fine, but the numerator has to be the number of ordered draws as well so the ratio is the probability you seek.

Comment: I guess my issue is if I want the total number of ordered 3 of a kind permutations, why not just use nPr (so 5*4*3*2*1 = 120). Wouldn't that give the number of ordered permutations? Mathematically, I can discount it blindly, but I don't really understand what that discount represents. I tried using the same method for a full house too (and I am off by the same factor of 10), which I know it is the 5!/(3!2!) issue but I am just not linking things together from a what they represent and/or why point of view.

Comment: $120$ is the factor between combinations and permutations.  You can count either as long as you are consistent.  One way to count the combinations is $4 \choose 3$ to select the aces and $\frac 12 \cdot 48 \cdot 44$ for the other two cards with the $\frac 12$ taking care of the two orders to select them.

Answer (score 0):

In your calculation, $B$ can be Jack for example and $C$ can be Queen or the other way around. So is $AAABC$ distinct from $AAACB$ ?

Comment: To win three of a kind, AAABC and AAACB are not distinct. However, the way I am doing it in this method is sort of first assuming an order, and then accounting for the fact that order does not matter (so adjusting for that)

Comment: @passerby if you don't divide by $2!$ then $AAABC$ and $AAACB$ will be treated as distinct

Comment: I guess my issue I can understand the problem from the nCk method point of view. I can also understand the logic behind doing just (# of unordered three of a kind) / (# of total 5 card hands unordered). More specifically, I get in the unordered / unordered case it is just (13 * [(4*3*2) / 3!] * [48*44/2!] / (52*51*50*49*48/5!). I am just not getting the logical connection for the discounts when I think about doing the problem from a 1st card, 2nd card, etc. approach (probably because it is the most cumbersome method)